# Javascript: read Array of Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have two .js files. In one, I want to fill an array with objects, that have two properties. In the other file I want to loop over the array and work with the objects properties.

My coding looks like this:

file1.js

```
var selection = new Object();
selection.column = "";
selection.term = "";

var selectionContainer = new Array();
...
press: function(){
 var i;
 for (i=1;i<=selectionContainer.length;i++){
  selection = selectionContainer[i];
  alert("Search Term: " + selection.column + selection.term);
 }
}
```

file2.js

```
change: function(oEvent){
 selection.column = "someText";
 selection.term = "someOtherText";
 selectionContainer[nrOfEntries] = selection;
}
```

When executing the javascript I receive 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'column' of undefined'.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JS arrays begin with index `0`, and the last element will be at the `.length - 1`. So you need to change your loop to start at `0` and use `<` rather than `<=`:

```
for (i=0;i<selectionContainer.length;i++){
```

The error you received, `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'column' of undefined'`, is because when your counter got up to `selectionContainer.length` you tried to read an element just past the end of the array, which in itself doesn't give an error, it just returns `undefined`, but then `undefined.column` gives the error.

But also - though it's a bit hard to tell because I'm not sure about the code you don't show - in the code you *do* show it looks like you are filling your array with multiple references to the *same* object, because in your `change` function you update the properties of the existing `selection` object and then put a reference to that object into the array. I believe you need to create a new object at that point:

```
change: function(oEvent){
  selection = new Object();
  selection.column = "someText";
  selection.term = "someOtherText";
  selectionContainer[nrOfEntries] = selection;
}
```

...but an easier way is to just use an object literal:

```
change: function(oEvent){
  selectionContainer[nrOfEntries] = { column : "someText", term : "someText" };
}
```

You don't say what `nrOfEntries` is, but you don't need a separate variable to keep track of the number of elements in the array when JS provides you with the `.length` property. In any case if you're just trying to add to the end of the array you can do this:

```
  selectionContainer.push( { column : "someText", term : "someText" } );
```

In general it is considered best practice to use array literals and object literals to create empty arrays and objects, so the beginning of your code could be:

```
var selection = {};
...
var selectionContainer = [];
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all - why you start the loop from the index 1. Isn't it correct if you start with the first element:

```
for (var i=0;i<selectionContainer.length;i++) {
```

Second, it is better to use the push method to add elements to the array. For example:

```
selectionContainer.push(selection);
nrOfEntries = selectionContainer.length;
```

If that doesn't help then we need more information about nrOfEntries and how it is changed.

Comment: First of all - why you end the loop at index i<=selectionContainer.length. Isn't it correct if you end with the last element + 1;

Comment: Correct. I missed to remove the =

Answer (score 0):

```
    change: function(oEvent){
    selection.column = "someText";
    selection.term = "someOtherText";
    selectionContainer[nrOfEntries] = selection;    
}
```

Change it to

```
    change: function(oEvent) {
        selectionContainer.push({column : 'someText', term : 'someOtherText});
}
```

You don t need i anymore, and you avoid to forget to fill selectionContainer[0]

Comment: Your object literal syntax is incorrect: use colons, not equals signs.